# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, error-handling, attributes

I've got a problem with some code im writing.

Im getting an error. AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'. when running the following code.

```
BosCle = get_tables('https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201710170CLE.html')
```

Get_tables is a funktion that goes to the webpage and gets the tables on this webpage. The minutes played is given in a min:sec format. 
I want to change this and do not know why this does not work.

```
BosCle[0]['MP'].dtypes
OUTPUT: MP           object
        MP           object
        dtypes:      object
```

Im then trying to split the string with the following code.

```
BosCle[0]['MP'].str.split(':')
```

I've tried str.replace, or str.split which also would be viable  options and it gives the same error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-802e713eb38b> in <module>()
----> 1 BosCle[0]['MP'].str.split(':')
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4370             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   4371                 return self[name]
-> 4372             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   4373 
   4374     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Hope that someone can help.

Here is the data in the table.

```
Starters    Team    Opponent    Away/Home   MP    FG    FGA   FG%
Player 1    BOS     CLE         A          39:12  3     5     .6    
Player 2    BOS     CLE         A          32:31  2     2     1.    
Player 3    BOS     CLE         A          31:53  1     5     .2    
Player 4    BOS     CLE         A          29:01  5     5     1    
Player 5    BOS     CLE         A          25:11  6     10     .6    
Player 6    BOS     CLE         A          7:12   1     5     .2    
Player 7    BOS     CLE         A          9:12   0     5     0    
Player 8    BOS     CLE         A          0      0     0     0    
Player 9    BOS     CLE         A          0      0     0     0
```

Comment: Why would they be viable options if the dtypes are object? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you also add some dummy data?

Comment: Do you expect the dataframe to have an attribute `str`? Why?

Comment: The error say that there is no attribute `str` on `BosCle[0]['MP']`, so you cannot do `BosCle[0]['MP'].str`.

Comment: Yeah i can try to add the table aswell.

Comment: an object is a string in a pandas dataframe if im not wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From your example it looks like `BosCle[0]['MP']` is not a single object but rather a DataFrame. If you go one level deeper and reach the object `str` will work.

Comment: ['MP'] is a column in the dataframe, how can i go deeper than that?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense in the data you posted. The data in the table is not exactly what it is, because when I entered two rows and tried running dtypes I got a key error 0:
`>>> df
   Starters Team Opponent Away/Home     MP  FG  FGA  FG%
0  Player 1  BOS      CLE         A  39:12   3    5  0.6
1  Player 2  BOS      CLE         A  32:31   2    2  1.0
>>> df[0]['MP'].dtypes
...
KeyError: 0`

Comment: Well i dont know how to set it up as a dataframe in this, so i dont know if thats the problem, i can try sending u a screenshot of the data if that would help?

Comment: Let's start with these outputs you can send. Try running these two commands:
1) `type(BosCle[0]['MP'])`
2) `BosCle[0]['MP'].head()`

Comment: Alright. 
    'type(BosCle[0]['MP'])'
Gives me the following output:
    pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

The function.
    BosCle[0]['MP'].head()
Gives the following table.
MP MP
0 39:36 39:36
1 39:21 39:21
2 36:32 36:32
3 32:07 32:07
4 5:15         5:15

Comment: Okay im not so good at formatting in comments. The first function gives the output "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame", the second function gives back a table with rows [1,2,3,4] and column-header [MP,MP] and the numbers are the same in both columns. [39:36,39:21,36:32,32:07,5:15]

Comment: difficult to understand from the comment. But Like I said initially, seems looks like it's a dataframe of dataframes. What happens if you do type(BosCle[0]['MP']['MP']), or maybe even BosCle[0]['MP']['MP'].str.split(':')